# Magento Module PHP Caching? Or Server Caching PHP?

Tags: php, apache, magento, caching, magento-1.5

Does Magento cache the php of a module installed?

I have an export to CSV module that I've modified in a number of ways with no results at all. Finally I deleted the content of the main part of the module that writes the (Csv.php) and in admin I can still export to CSV?

So does magento cache modules or the php of modules anywhere, and if so how can I clear it / reset the module for my modifications?

Thanks.

EDIT: I've made the same changes on a local host version of Magento and got the results I was after. So secondary question is if Magento doesn't - would my server be caching the PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Go to **System > Tools > Compilation** and click the **Disable** button.

---

Take 2: Files in `app/code/core/` can be overridden in `app/code/community/` and likewise by `app/code/local`.  If you edit a file in `core` that is present in one of the other directories then your edit has no effect.

---

Take 3: If you have APC or XCache installed on your server then it *might* not have noticed a changing file. Restart the apache or php-cgi process.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I went into Compilation and it has Compiler Status: Disabled. Compilation State: Not Compiled. Any other ideas?

Comment: You're awesome - it shows that no matter how confident you are you should always go through suggestions. For some reason the module was installed in both /community and /local. Much appreciated.